# Error when update facebook_audience_network to 0.9.0

Tags: flutter, facebook-ads-api

Whan update my facebook_audience_network to 0.9.0 then I got this error message

```
[com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.4.0] C:\Users\007\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\25a494723d7018266df203e7ea11ccc5\audience-network-sdk-6.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-55 Error:
    Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-55
[com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.4.0] C:\Users\007\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\25a494723d7018266df203e7ea11ccc5\audience-network-sdk-6.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndroidManifest of audience-network-sdk-6.4.0 includes 'queries' element, it requires fixed Gradle plugin.
I've solved the problem by rising Gradle plugin version to 3.6.4.

Here there are more info -
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/preparing-your-build-for-package-visibility-in-android-11.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's just a package mismatch, try to delete pubspec.lock and run

flutter clean

flutter pub get